# java - string.split with regex

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have the following file.

```
ABD,2131
"AB, D", 383
```

I iterate the file and would like to split the values.

```
line.split(",");
```

what it gives:

```
ABD 2131  [2 values]
"AB  D" 383 [3 values]
```

what I would like to have

```
 ABD 2131 [2 values]
"AB, D" 383 [2 values]
```

So what I would like to do is to ignore comas surrounded by quotation.

Comment: regex101.com is your friend. Just try some things. You should tell us with an [edit] if you always have two fields in the input.

Comment: you mean `input.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)")`

Comment: i am afraid it doesn't work when I have empty rows
"AB, D", 383,,,,,,

Comment: needed this
 line.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1)